# Flagging questions or upvote comment?

Tags: discussion

During flagging as duplicate, a comment is added to the post.

This comment gets upvoted automatically when another user flags the question as a duplicate of the respective post.

So, "confirming" the duplication leads to an upvote on the "Possible duplicate of... ".

**My question is:**

> Does upvoting this kind of comments also automatically cast a "duplicate" flag?

I tried to find related info but no luck so far.

Comment: this seems unlikely to me. Vote to Close is vote to close(with that feature of upvote comment), a powerfull tool,  and upvote a comment is upvote a comment, which has the smallest impact in the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does upvoting this kind of comments also automatically cast a "duplicate" flag?

No. You can easily check that.

Try to upvote an auto-generated comment, no vote will be cast.

Comment: I did check and indeed no flag appeared in the flag history. But I was wondering if high-rep users see anything else. Thanks for clearing that up!